# grunt-contrib-copy how to copy all the vendor fonts in build

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

my tree is like

```
public/system/lib
       angular
       bootstrap
          fonts
       font-awesome
          fonts
       jquery
```

my goal is put all the fonts folders
in my public/build/fonts

so I've tried with:

```
copy: {
            fonts: {
                cwd: 'public/system/lib/**/fonts/',
                src: '*',
                dest: 'public/build/fonts',
                expand: true
            }
        },
```

but it doesn't work.
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
cwd: ['public/system/lib/bootstrap/fonts/*', 'public/system/lib/font-awesome/fonts/*'],
```

Comment: icons are in fonts so you don't need fonts/**